# A way of limiting the scope the JavaScript/CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, scope

**Problem Statement:**
I need to find a solution where JavaScript and CSS wouldn't collide with the other scripts (widgets) running on the HTML page.

**Proposed Solution**
Does anyone know a way of limiting the scope the JavaScript? There are two ways I know of

1. Using IFrame to load the widget
2. Using Frameset to load the widget

Using both of the options, it permanently removes any way of having any kind JavaScript or CSS conflict. Does anyone know of any other way?

Comment: Please promise me you won't go iframe

Comment: You would never know if two css files may interfere with eachother. As for javascript, wrap it in an IIFE.

Comment: @Martijn Why avoid iframes, exactly? Avoiding framesets I could understand as they've been removed from HTML. But, iframes are still often used for embedded content, which a widget may very well count as.

Comment: Iframes are like eval(). You use those when there are no reasonable alternate solutions.  This case really doesn't need this, at all

Answer (score 2):

When including multiple widgets/plugins/libraries on the same page, you will always have the possibility of conflicts between them. Obviously, the only foolproof solution to this would be to use an iframe, however that is often not ideal due to either seo purposes, or the widget needs to do more than can be done within an iframe.

There is no way to guarantee one widget won't conflict with another unless you wrote the widgets yourself with that possibility in mind (other than by using iframes of course.)

Namespacing is a common technique to avoid conflicts between css and js. from a css point of view, it just means using an id or class on the container element of the widget and using that class in every style being used by the plugin (note however that due to the nature of css, this doesn't absolutely guarantee something won't conflict.) in js, it means storing all of your methods and variables within private scopes that are only accessible from a single unique property on `window` similar to how jquery defines `window.jQuery`.

```
.myWidget .header {...}
.myWidget .footer {...}
.myWidget .header a {...}
```

and

```
(function(window){
    function doSomething() {...}
    function doSomethingElse() {...}
    window.myWidget = {
        fn1: doSomething,
        fn2: doSomethingElse
    };
}(window);
myWidget.fn1();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's some really cool stuff on the horizon that you can begin using now. @KevinB's answer is right-on (+1'ed) for the *current and last generation of web browsers*, but I urge you to start looking into **[Web Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/)** which will isolate your "widgets" exactly as you are desiring.

The good news is you can start today using web components now with **[Google's Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/)** library/polyfill.